# MembershipUser IsOnline always returns false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Contrary to other posts i have googled which have a problem with IsOnline always returning true, i'm finding that IsOnline always returns false.  I have used both Membership.GetUser(username, false) and GetAllUsers() but both have IsOnline set to false for all users.  I know that at the very least it should have me as online because I have just logged in. (Or am I missing what IsOnline is all about?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsOnline simply check, in a TimeFrame specified in the web.config, how many user are online.

Everytime a logged user visit a page the Membership save the `LastActivityDate`.

Maybe you are getting false, because you didn't set the `UserIsOnlineTimeWindow` in the web.config section of your membership provider. [Look here for documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.userisonlinetimewindow.aspx)

Comment: Yes it was missing from web.config and that fixed it.  Thank you.  I am still a little confused as GetNumberOfUsersOnline was returning a non-zero number at the time.